# Wrap oidc provider

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, oauth, openid-connect

I have been tasked with moving our identity management to a 3rd party and adding oidc support to an existing application suite. So first a little backstory…

This existing application suite already uses Bearer JWTs for authentication across the multitude of service. These JWTs are signed id_tokens in the oauth2 world and we use them as access_tokens. All of the existing services heavily rely on the current id_tokens containing specific claims custom to our applications. Our team is most comfortable with dotnet, but the application suite contains services in many different languages.

My ideal solution to this problem would be to add oidc support to a single new service that performs an identity transform to a new set of tokens. This new service would perform the Identity Provider roll within the application suite only, but leave the management of the identities, login flows, etc. to the 3rd party IDP.

I have been looking into how to achieve this with ASP dotnet core authentication framework, but there does not appear to be a way to provide this functionality without using a paid product like IdentityServer or rolling your own solution.

So my questions are:

- Will this design expose any security vulnerabilities?
- Can this be built using existing framework tools available today?

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to add your own internal Identity token provider (like IdentityServer) that can issue tokens that all your internal clients and API trusts.

[image]

Then IdentityServer can let users authenticate using their 3rd party service, like this:

[image]

The advantage here is that your services not not need to depend on external tokens. You can add/remove authentication providers as you like. Also, clients and APIs prefer to only trust tokens from one source.  In your internal token provider, you can lookup additional data that can be added to the tokens.

Comment: This looks like I would need to go all the way and support user federation. Is that accurate?

Comment: by abstracting your internal applications from the 3rd party token services, you can ensure all the tokens always contain the required claims. Sometimes you might not have that control when you rely on a third-party provider. I know it will be some task to add a middleman into the mix, but then it is easy to also integrate with partners and enables new possibilities.